# Is there a way of using a boolean between a grouped object and a regular object on Inskcape?

Tags: inkscape, layers, path

I have a grouped object and I would like to cut it in half. For this, I created another object (a rectangle) and tried *Path>Difference* but nothing happens (neither with any of the other booleans). I've noticed that this has happened before and the common point is that there's always a group involved.

How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boolean operations won't work with groups.  They will only work properly with two closed paths.

Anyway, here's one method to work around that. Before you proceed maybe make a duplicate of your design before you try this, just in case.

1. Make sure your design is ungrouped. Set your design to have no fill, just a stroke, so you can see what is going on.
2. Place a rectangle to cut over the top of the design, with only a stroke and no fill
3. Place a filled rectangle underneath everything, big enough to surround all the shapes.
4. With the Select and Transform tool <kbd>F1</kbd>, click and drag a selection around the inside shapes, including the rectangle to use for cutting in half.
5. Do *Path > Combine*
6. Select the combined path and the outer filled rectangle
7. Do *Path > Division*
8. Select and delete the pieces you don't want
9. Select and recolour the pieces.

Example

[image]